# Conditional COUNT within CASE statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

Table 1, is a list of clients, what membership they have, what service they used, and the date the service was used

Table 2, is just table 1 grouped by month and membership type, then a count of the service sessions

What I am trying to do is count membership sessions only by particular service types. This is what I have so far, it returns an error saying 'Service_Type' is not in an aggregate function or group by clause, when I put 'Service_Type' in a group by, the query has no errors but the SESSIONS column is all NULL.

```
SELECT 
  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(t1.Date),MONTH(t1.Date),1)AS 'Draft_Date', 
  Membership,
  CASE 
    WHEN Membership = 5 AND Service_Type = 'A' THEN COUNT(*)
    WHEN Membership = 2 AND Service_Type IN ('J','C')
  END AS'SESSIONS' 
FROM Table1 t1 
GROUP BY DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(t1.Date),MONTH(t1.Date),1),Membership
```

The case statement will include all memberships and service types but I think this is enough for my example. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've been on this for days.

Table 1
[image: Table 1]

Table 2
[image: Table 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there! I've made a few changes:

```
SELECT 
  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(t1.Date), MONTH(t1.Date),1) AS Draft_Date, 
  Membership,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.Membership = 5 AND t1.Service_Type = 'A' THEN 1 END) as m5stA,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.Membership = 2 AND t1.Service_Type IN ('J','C') THEN 1 END) as m2stJC
FROM Table1 t1 
GROUP BY YEAR(t1.Date), MONTH(t1.Date), Membership
```

Changes:

- Avoid using apostrophes to alias column names, use ascii standard " double quotes if you must
- When doing a conditional count, put the count outside the CASE WHEN, and have the case when return something (any non null thing will be fine - i used 1, but it could also have been 'x' etc) when the condition is met. Don't put an ELSE - CASE WHEN will return null if there is no ELSE and the condition is not met, and nulls don't COUNT (you could also write ELSE NULL, though it's redundant)
- Qualify all your column names, always - this helps keep the query working when more tables are added in future, or even if new columns with the same names are added to existing tables
- You forgot a THEN in the second WHEN
- You don't necessarily need to GROUP BY the output of DATEFROMPARTS. When a deterministic function is used (always produces the same output from the same inputs) the db is smart enough to know that grouping on the inputs is also fine
- Your example data didn't contain any data that would make the COUNT count 1+ by the way, but I'm sure you will have other conditional counts that work out (it just made it harder to test)

Comment: Thank you for the solution and other notes, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

use sum

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(t1.Date),MONTH(t1.Date),1) AS Draft_Date , Membership,
sum(CASE WHEN Membership = 5 AND Service_Type = 'A' THEN 1  else 0 end),
sum(case WHEN Membership = 2 AND Service_Type IN ('J','C') then 1 else 0 end)

FROM Table1 t1 group by DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(t1.Date),MONTH(t1.Date),1)
```