# SQL return value even if there is no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

How to get value out even if result is empty?

My Query is

```
select MEDIA_ID,BARCODE,COUNT(MEDIA_ID) OVER() AS 'NUM',USE_BY_DATE
 from MEDIA_V
 where PRODUCT_NUMBER='9SattlePlates'
 and SUBLOT_PARENT_ID  IS NOT NULL
 and RESERVED_BATCH_ID IS NULL
 and QUANTITY > 0
 AND USE_BY_DATE < GETDATE()
```

Now I got only column name, but I need '0' or at least something. Is this possible?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL Server Management.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you need to have some other table with the "base" data you want to have rows of and LEFT JOIN the above thing.

Comment: `SQL Server Management.` is the DBA tool, not the database

Comment: Why do you need to return a dummy value if there are no results in the first place? All languages can handle empty results. Whatever the actual problem is, there's a better solution than returning dummy data

Comment: @siggemannen Why was this closed?

Comment: @Charlieface, to me the question is very unclear, should it return a single dummy row, should the row contain media_id, or just a 0, there is no sample data, "I need" and "at least something" is not a proper specification

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a virtual `VALUES` table and left join everything else to it. Note that the `WHERE` conditions need to go in the `ON`.

```sql
select
  mv.MEDIA_ID,
  mv.BARCODE,
  COUNT(mv.MEDIA_ID) OVER() AS NUM,
  mv.USE_BY_DATE
from (values (1) ) as v(dummy)
left join MEDIA_V as mv
    -- other joins here
   on mv.PRODUCT_NUMBER = '9SattlePlates'
  and mv.SUBLOT_PARENT_ID  IS NOT NULL
  and mv.RESERVED_BATCH_ID IS NULL
  and mv.QUANTITY > 0
  AND mv.USE_BY_DATE < GETDATE()
```

You can use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` to replace the nulls if there are no rows.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, but is there something else?

```
IF (select COUNT(MEDIA_ID)
             from MEDIA_V
             where PRODUCT_NUMBER='9SattlePlates'
             and SUBLOT_PARENT_ID  IS NOT NULL
             and RESERVED_BATCH_ID IS NULL
             and QUANTITY > 0
             AND USE_BY_DATE < GETDATE())>0
  BEGIN 
    (select MEDIA_ID,BARCODE,COUNT(MEDIA_ID) OVER() AS 'NUM',USE_BY_DATE
 from MEDIA_V
 where PRODUCT_NUMBER='9SattlePlates'
 and SUBLOT_PARENT_ID  IS NOT NULL
 and RESERVED_BATCH_ID IS NULL
 and QUANTITY > 0
 AND USE_BY_DATE < GETDATE())
 END
  ELSE 
    select 0 as 'NUM'
```

Comment: This isn't a solution at all. Whatever calls this will throw an error due to the unexpected results. Why do you want to return dummy values in the first place? *All* client languages can handle empty results

Comment: You haven't explained the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: This is executing in background and results is returning to another background process on which I do not have impact. So i need to return a value. My solution is working now.

Answer (score -1):

In SSMS (or any SQL server script) you can check [@@ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to see how many rows a query (or other DML) has affected.

You can also use a CASE statement to conditionally count rows.

```
SELECT MEDIA_ID,
       BARCODE,
       COUNT(
           CASE WHEN QUANTITY > 0
                   AND SUBLOT_PARENT_ID  IS NOT NULL
                   AND RESERVED_BATCH_ID IS NULL
               THEN MEDIA_ID
           ELSE 
               NULL
           END
       ) AS 'NUM',
       USE_BY_DATE
 FROM MEDIA_V
 WHERE PRODUCT_NUMBER='9SattlePlates'                   
 AND USE_BY_DATE < GETDATE()
```

e.g. see [Conditional COUNT within CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247891/conditional-count-within-case-statement)